# OSX 10.8 OpenGL Extensions

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to have a full listing of the OpenGL extensions supported in OSX 10.8?

Comment: Nice question, but MacOS 10.8 is still under NDA and should not be talked about outside of [Apple's official dev forums](http://devforums.apple.com), which is the only place where we're officially allowed to talk about Mountain Lion.

Comment: ah, so this is why I couldnt find anything.. TY, may I at least know if new extensions are supported compared to 10.7.4?

Comment: Um, wouldn't this be mostly hardware dependent?

Comment: Ian: I believe Apple chooses one version of OpenGL and one set of extensions for each OS.

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't updated their capabilities table yet, but I found this table for 10.8:
http://arek.bdmonkeys.net/GLInfo/GLInfo.html